# what does it mean for function(arg)[Arg]

Tags: r

when I am practicing with state datasets,

I saw this way to show the levels:

```
myState <-as.data.frame(cbind(state.x77,region=state.region))
myState <- cbind(myState,regionName=levels(state.region)[state.region])
```

So the actual regionname will be bound, but here I don't know how to interpret the `levels(state.region)[state.region]` here.
I get no idea why why `levels(state.region)[state.region]` will return a character (vector?) of length 50 here.

Originally I thought it could be done by loop, throwing in index, and get the correct regionname back. But all in a sudden, throw in the variable name will just do it perfectly, so I just wondering what happened inside.

I knew `levels(state.region)[3]` will show the third levels in the `state.region` factor, will this help interpret when the number is replaced by the factor itself?

I also tried to search if this is asked before but don't see things similar or probably I don't get the right keyword.

Really appreciate for any help

Comment: More or less, it's accessing by name instead of index to get the name and not the index. But I'm unsure this is really your question...

Comment: My question sounds like that, " how does it match/ add the correct regionname if it didn't pass the index but the name?"

Comment: You're searching how the factors are subset in both case in fact (by index or by name) right ?

Comment: sorry that I still don't get it,  let me reframe my question again, why `levels(state.region)[state.region]` will return a character (vector?) of length 50. Originally I thought it could be done by loop, throwing in index, and get the correct regionname back. But all in a sudden, throw in the variable name will just do it perfectly, so I just wondering what happened inside.

Comment: Awww, ok I get it (I think). I'll try to give an explanation by steps as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get this by inspecting the things:

First state.region is a factor, let's see it:

```
> dput(state.region)
structure(c(2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Northeast", "South", "North Central", 
"West"), class = "factor")
```

calling `levels` give us the character vectors of the factor's Labels:

```
> dput(levels(state.region))
c("Northeast", "South", "North Central", "West")
```

where the fun comes is when you give the factor as a selector to this character vector, the easiest way to visualize it is to call as.integer on the factor:

```
> dput(as.integer(state.region))
c(2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L)
```

so basically what those compound command ends up to do is:

```
 > c("Northeast", "South", "North Central", "West")[c(2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L)]
```

A simpler syntax to get the character vector would be to use `as.vector(state.region)`.

Comment: That's really helpful!!!!, I never knew R can do things like this, especially the last part of the compound command. And sorry that I can't vote yet, or I should vote up definitely.